# Regex optional group selection doesn't work

Tags: regex

I want to extract the numbers from the following text:

```
Something_Time 10 min (Time in Class T>60�C Something Something )
Something_Time 899 min (Time in Class 35�C<T<=40�C Something Something )
Something_Time 0 min (Time in Class T<=-25�C Something Something )
```

So what I need is:

```
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|    Group 1    |    Group 2    |    Group 3    |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|      10       |      60       |               |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|      899      |      35       |      40       |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
|      0        |               |      -25      |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|
```

Group 2 as lower bound and group 3 as upper bound.

I tried the following regex expression:

```
^.* (\d{1,6}) min .*(?:[ \>](\-?\d{1,2}))?.*(?:[\=](\-?\d{1,2}))?.*$
```

This unfortunately does not match groups 2 and 3. It works for the second line as soon as the `?` is removed from the end of both groups. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure 60 has to be in group 2 and not in group 3 (since T>60)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^Something_Time (\d{1,6}) min(?:.*?[ >](-?\d{1,2}))?(?:.*?[ =](-?\d{1,2}))?.*$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7yEJDi/1/)

1. `^` Matches start of string.
2. `Something_Time`  Matches 'Something_Time '
3. `(\d{1,6})` Group 1: 1 - 6 digits
4. `min` Matches ' min'
5. `(?:.*?[ >](-?\d{1,2}))?` Optional group that matches 0 or more non-newline characters followed by either a space or '>' followed by a number (optional '-' followed by up to 2 digits). The number is placed in Group 2.
6. `(?:.*?[ =](-?\d{1,2}))?` Optional group that matches 0 or more non-newline characters followed by either a space or '=' followed by a number (optional '-' followed by up to 2 digits). The number is placed in Group 3.
7. `.*` Matches 0 or more non-newline characters.
8. `$` Matches the end of the string or a newline that precedes the end of the string.

In Python:

```
import re

tests = [
    'Something_Time 10 min (Time in Class T>60�C Something Something )',
    'Something_Time 899 min (Time in Class 35�C<T<=40�C Something Something )',
    'Something_Time 0 min (Time in Class T<=-25�C Something Something )'
]

for test in tests:
    m = re.match(r'^Something_Time (\d{1,6}) min(?:.*?[ >](-?\d{1,2}))?(?:.*?[ =](-?\d{1,2}))?.*$', test)
    if m:
        print(m.groups())
```

Prints:

```
('10', '60', None)
('899', '35', '40')
('0', None, '-25')
```